# jQuery .live() only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have a simple jQuery AJAX code which generates XHTML code:

```
$("a.close").live("click", function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();      
    $( '#info' ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
});
```

This code works great once. My div closes and everything is fine, but if I click on the link that opens up my `#info` div a second time then I can't close the div. I get no errors in Firebug and I can't solve the problem.

Comment: This could potentially be selector scope. Can you show the method/code block that `live` call is in?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some more code, and the HTML markup involved.

Comment: Are you adding any click handlers to an ancestor of the `a.close` element after  the AJAX call? Or are you sure that the `<a>` has the class `close` after the AJAX? I assume your content is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `returning false` instead of calling `e.preventDefault`?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as jQuery normalizes these things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#info").fadeOut('slow').remove();
```

It's possible you're adding multiple '#info' boxes, but not actually removing the old ones - just hiding them.